# How can I cultivate mycelium for food and fertilizer in my apartment?

Tags: apartment, mushrooms

Having watched Paul Stamet's TED Talk, [Six Ways Mushrooms Can Save the World](http://www.ted.com/talks/paul_stamets_on_6_ways_mushrooms_can_save_the_world.html), I'd like to be able to cultivate mycelium in an urban environment. I would like to harvest it for food

I don't have a balcony. I have good northern exposure window (if that matters). Where do I start? What are good resources to look at?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't grow mushrooms on a balcony.  A cool basement closet is a better choice (disclaimer I want to get more into this but used to have some experience with commercial kits).

The first step is to research thoroughly the type of mushroom you want to grow.  Different mushrooms require different growing media and have different temperature constraints.  You may also want to weed out mushroom varieties.  Are you looking to rot wood?  Is manure-based mushroom growing acceptable to you?  What temperatures can you commit to, etc.

Once you get this then the steps are obtaining the media, inoculating it, and growing mushrooms in the innoculated media.  These stages are relatively species-dependent, but if you are looking at where to get started, I hope this will help.

In general, the primary resources I would recommend actually are just googling how to grow specific mushrooms, and going to your local library and doing general research there.

Comment: +1! Good places to start. Suppose though, I don't have a basement? (I live near the top floor of the building).

Comment: The reason why a basement might be preferred is you get fewer temperature fluctuations.  In an apartment, any closet will probably do.